# SvelteKit readable store initialize on client-side only

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have an authToken readable store that can only be initialized from the client side. It's shared between many components, so it exists in it's own `.ts` file:

*// auth.ts*

```js
export const authToken = readable("", (set) => {
  const updateToken = async () => {
    const token = await fetchToken() // ... fetch API token
    set(token)
  };
  setTimeout(fetchToken, 0);
});
```

With SvelteKit/Vite, this code is being run on the server side and failing during compile. How can I force this to only initialize for the first time onMount (without it being in a `.svelte` component)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`browser` flag](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser), e.g.:

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';

export const authToken = readable("", (set) => {
  const updateToken = async () => {
    // ...
  };

  if (browser)
    updateToken();
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, was unable to find any reference about this in the docs when discussing the Stores. Thanks!